# Compress / Decompress with LZ4

Tags: c++, lossless-compression, lz4

When I compress / decompress with LZ4, it gives me something that has nothing to do with the origin string.

For example "1234" is good, but not with a sentence.

**Here is the corrected code, thanks for the answers** :

```
   int Compress(const char* source, char* dest, int sourceSize, int maxDestSize)
    {
        return LZ4_compress_default(source, dest, sourceSize, maxDestSize);
    }

    int Decompress(const char* source, char* dest, int compressedSize, int maxDecompressedSize)
    {
        return LZ4_decompress_safe(source, dest, compressedSize, maxDecompressedSize);
    }

    int main()
    {
        char source[1024] = "Arguing that you don\'t care about the right to privacy because you have nothing to hide is no different than saying you don\'t care about free speech because you have nothing to say.";

        char buff[1024 * 4] = { 0 };
        char buff_a[1024 * 4] = { 0 };

        int x = Compress(source, buff, strlen(source), sizeof(buff));
        printf("\nBYTE COMPRESSED : %i\nDATA COMPRESSED : \n", x);
        for (int i = 0; i < x; i++)
            printf(" %2x", (unsigned)buff[i]);

        int y = Decompress(buff, buff_a, x, sizeof(buff_a));
        printf("\n\nBYTE DECOMPRESSED : %i\nDATA DECOMPRESSED : \n", y);
        for (int i = 0; i < y; i++)
            printf(" %02x", (unsigned)buff_a[i]);

        printf("\n\n\n\nEXIT\n");
        getchar();
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: `strlen(buff)` - how did you come to think a compressed LZ4 byte stream was synonymous with a null-terminated string? Pretty sure that should be `x`. And fyi, `%s` for "printing" the compressed stream is also wrong. You'll likely need a hex dump if you want to "see" what the compressed stream octets look like.

Comment: `LZ4_compress_default()` returns the compressed size, you're saving this as `x` already - you just need to pass this into the decompression function.

Comment: In Server / Client if I want to compress the exchanges, I must first send the size of the compressed bytes, not possible to decompress without having it?

Comment: You seem to be missing definitions for `LZ4_compress_default` and `LZ4_decompress_safe` - have you missed a header?  You're obviously missing `<cstdio>` at least.  And is there really any need for the `Compress` and `Decompress` wrappers in a *minimal* example?  Finally, should your second output loop range from `0` to `y`, rather than `0` to `x`?

Comment: Is just for exemple, all headers are included before.